# How to get gradle dependency working in Android project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to use the library `org.json:json:20131018` in my Android project, but when I add it as a gradle dependency I get:

```
WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20131018 is ignored for debug as it may be 
conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
    In case of problem, please repackage with jarjar to change the class packages

WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20131018 is ignored for release as it may be 
conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
    In case of problem, please repackage with jarjar to change the class packages

/Users/jim/dev/myapplication-android/myapplication-api/src/main/java/net
/myapplication/android/api/some/package/MyClass.java:18: 
error: cannot find symbol
        return XML.toJSONObject(xml).toString();
               ^
   symbol:   variable XML
   location: class MyClass
```

I need the `XML` class from this library, and the Android `org.json` package does not have this.

If I exclude the dependency, then I still get this error:

```
/Users/jim/dev/myapplication-android/myapplication-api/src/main/java/net
/myapplication/android/api/some/package/MyClass.java:18: 
error: cannot find symbol
        return XML.toJSONObject(xml).toString();
               ^
   symbol:   variable XML
   location: class MyClass
```

So I need to be able to include this library.

Comment: I don't think you need to include that library in gradle. What the error is saying is that it finds a more updated version of that library internally on Android... just erase that dependency and try a normal import in your class.

Comment: @JavierM - But the version it forces, which is inside the `android.jar`, does not contain the class that I need which is at `org.json.XML`.

Comment: then sync with gradle the latest version which is the `20140107` check the [Maven Central](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20140107), perhaps such method exists in that one...

Comment: @JavierM - Tried that. However, the version `20131018` has the method anyway, as it worked when building with Maven. The issue is that when I have the dependency when building with gradle, it gets ignored because `android.jar` has it's own version.

Comment: Not so sure if it's possible but try adding a dependency of that library for the debug/release flavors in the build.gradle, perhaps it overrides the internal library..

Comment: @JavierM - It was a good idea, however I tried both `productFlavors` and (for the hell of it) `buildTypes` - but to no avail :(